# what is the rational class in java?

Tags: java, class, rational-number

I was assigned to make a rational class by java but I really don't understand what is required as below:

> 1. Rational Implement a rational number class: Rational Augment your class with methods for:
>
>    1. Initialization (Constructor): parameters are numerator and
>         denominator as integers. You must have 3 constructors as follows:
>
>       - No Parameters: 0 / 1
>       - One Parameter (x): x / 1
>       - Two Parameters (x, y): x / y
>    2. `float getValue()`: returns the value of the number
>    3. [bonus] Rational `add(Rational r)`: adds to another rational number
>
> All your numbers should be saved in Reduced Form
>
> Augment your code with a driver class (that contains "main" method)
>   that constructs two Rational numbers, get the average of the two
>   numbers and prints it on the screen.

Comment: It's referring to the rational numbers.

Comment: You just need to make a class, which implement rational numbers, so it has two integer fields, the *numerator* and the *denominator*

Comment: Instead returning `1.333333...` for `12/9`, you want to reduce the value to `4/3`. Have you seen Euclid's (GCD) Algorithm?

Comment: Rational numbers are numbers which can be expressed as a fraction of two integers. For example. 1, 0.1, 5/4 and 0.35345 are all rational numbers. Pi isnt

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your time and effort

Answer (score 2):

This code implements some of your requirement, but the [bonus] task, and the usage of the reduced form is missing, it is up to you to finish it.

```
class Rational {

    private int nominator;
    private int denominator;

    public Rational() {
        this(0, 1);
    }

    public Rational(int nominator) {
        this(nominator, 1);
    }

    public Rational(int nominator, int denominator) {
        this.nominator = nominator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }


    public float getValue() {
        return nominator / (float) denominator;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's why I didn't do the hard parts :)

Comment: Thanks that was the thing that i couldn't understand